# ×TypeError: Cannot read property 'borders' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not sure as to why I'm getting this error:

```
render() {
  14 |   let { params } = this.props.match
  15 |   let country = this.state.countries.find(country => country.cca· === params.id)
> 16 |   let countryBorders = country.borders.map(border => this.state.countries.find(country => country.cca3 === border && country))
 | ^  17 |
```

18 |   return (
  19 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error implies `country` is `undefined`, which does indeed happen if

```
let country = this.state.countries.find(country => country.cca· === params.id)
```

ends up not finding a country with a `cca·` attribute required. Two things:

- Is that really `cca·` in your original code? It should probably be `cca` (though `cca·` is technically a valid identifier).
- Add a guard:

```py
let countryBorders = (country ? country.borders.map(border => this.state.countries.find(country => country.cca3 === border && country) : []);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of country? you need to make sure you're not trying to access a property for a value that doesn't exist yet.

Try something like this:

```
countryBorders = country && country.borders.map(border => this.state.countries.find(country => country.cca3 === border && country)) || []
```

Comment: class Countries extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            countries: props.Countries, 
            idx:0
        } 
    }